# asp.net Can a GridView have two DataSources?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Afternoon All,

I have a gridview that i am using to display a list of 'Actions' from a database.

I have a dropdown list that is connected to this gridview, this enables a user to filter the data via the 'Action Status' in the dropdown list ('Assigned', 'Inprogress' & 'Completed').  This works perfectly fine....

What i am trying to do is have another filter option available for the user, they would like to also filter by user name.  I have the datasource and the dropdown list set up for this but i can only have one datasource connected to my gridview?

Does anyone have a suggestionon how to enable the users to also filter by username as well as 'action status'?

Here is my code if you need to take a peek....

```
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsActions" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="Populate_grdAllActions_Filter" 
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddFilterStatus" Name="ActionStatusID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
         </asp:SqlDataSource>

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsActionsByUser" runat="server" 
               ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" 
               SelectCommand="Populate_grdAllActions_Filter_By_User" 
               SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddFilterUsers" Name="UserID" 
                     PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
             </SelectParameters>
         </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsFilterList" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ActionStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsFilterUsers" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserSimpleList]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <table style="width: 400px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="height: 25px"><b>Filter Options:</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 158px">
                Select Action Status:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFilterStatus" runat="server"  
                    DataTextField="ActionStatus" DataValueField="ActionStatusID" 
                 AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="dsFilterList"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="width: 158px">
                Select Actions by User:</td>
            <td>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFilterUsers" runat="server"  
                    DataTextField="UserFullName" DataValueField="UserID" 
                 AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="dsFilterUsers"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
     </table>

     <br/>

      <asp:GridView ID="grdActions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="dsActions" CssClass="mGrid" 
            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
           AllowPaging="True" PageSize="6" DataKeyNames="ActionID" Width="68%" >
      <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
    <Columns>
          <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ActionID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/UpdateAction.aspx?Edit={0}"
                DataTextField="ActionID" HeaderText="Action ID" >
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:HyperLinkField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" 
            SortExpression="Action" >
          <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" 
            SortExpression="Owner">
          <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetDate" HeaderText="Target Date" 
            SortExpression="TargetDate"  DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy} " >
          <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" />
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Action Status" HeaderText="Action Status" 
            SortExpression="Action Status" >
          <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" />
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
          </asp:BoundField>
     </Columns>
       <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Any help is much appriechiated in advance.

Regards
Betty

Comment: I don't know what your tables look like but from the description of your problem you want to view actions, and then actions by user, so in dsFilterUsers, wouldn't you have `SELECT * FROM [ActionStatus] WHERE user = userSelected` ? Thus instead of making another data source, just change the existing one and then re-bind it (`grdActions.DataBind()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which option the user selected, then set the Datasource in code-behind rather than wired them up in the aspx.

Pseudocode assumes that if the FilterUsers dropdown was selected, then bind to the Action By User data source:

```
if(IsPostBack){
    if(ddlFilterUsers.SelectedValue <> ""){
        grdActions.DataSource = dsActionsByUser;
        dsFilterUsers.DataBind();
        //etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind part, On **ddFilterStatus_SelectIndexChanged()** Event, Check for appropriate "Action Status" and Select the Data source as follows,

```
 if(ddFilterStatus.SelectedValue == someid1)
 {

     grdActions.DataSource =  appropriate datasource

 }
 else
 {
      grdActions.DataSource =  appropriate datasource
  }
  grdActions.DataBind()
```

Hope this helps...